# Loop invariant of a running sum array?

Tags: algorithm, loops, invariants, array-sum

So I was given this algorithm :

```
Algorithm RunningSum(int[] A)
n = A.length;
for i = 2 to n do
A[i] = A[i] + A[i - 1]
end
return A;
end
```

and I need to find the loop invariant
but I can figure out what the output could be...
lets say I have a array

```
a[4]= {1,2,4,3}
```

will the output be `a[4] = {1,3,6,7}` from `{1,(1+2),(2+4),(4+3)}` or will it be `a[4]={1,3,7,10}` from `{1,(1+2),(3+4),(7+3)}`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the algorithm is a description of [Fibonacci Series](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/examples/fibonacci-series). Here is a related post about [Fibonacci Loop Invariants](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444398/fibonacci-loop-invariants)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In computer science, a loop invariant is a property of a program loop that is true *before (and after) each iteration*.

Source: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant

For

> "property of a program loop" .. that is true

We can also say "logical condition" or just `boolean`. ;)

For the given code/loop/algorithm:

```cobol
Algorithm RunningSum(int[] A)
  n = A.length;
  for i = 2 to n do
    A[i] = A[i] + A[i - 1]
  end
  return A;
end
```

We can surely state, that:

- `i >= 2`
- AND `i <= n` (`<` or `<=` ..depends on your "language"...to be exact:)
- AND accordingly (in the scope of `i`):
  `A[i] == A[i] + A[i - 1]` (equality! not assignment)
- (`n == A.length`, `A == A` ... + all "tautologies" ;)

.. are *all* `true` "before (and after) each iteration", thus our "loop invariant(s)" (of concern)

Regarding "output"/algorithm interpretation, i more tend to:

> `a[4]={1,3,7,10}` from `{1,(1+2),(3+4),(7+3)}`

.#

Answer (score 0):

This may vary in some programming languages, but most common languages will produce the output `{1,3,7,10}`. The best way to find out is just run the code and print the output.

Answer (score 0):

This is a scan or prefix-sum operation. The invariant at the start of the loop body is that

`in iteration i, A[i] is the sum of all previous A[j]`

plus stuff about bounds and such.